# Efficient way to request touch focus from WindowManager?

Tags: android, events, focus, overlay

I have created two views on a FrameLayout, and requested focus to second. When I start the activity touch events hangs up for a while, then passes to my GL view. This takes random time I think (generally 5-10 seconds). It there a way to flush event queue?

I have a GLSurfaceView and I want draw an overlay SurfaceView above it. SurfaceView must be drawn on top of GLSurfaceView but input events must be delivered to opengl surface.
This is my activity,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mGLView= new SFView(this);
    mCanvas= new SFCanvas(this);

    mLayout=new FrameLayout(this);
    mLayout.addView(mCanvas);
    mLayout.addView(mGLView);

    setContentView(mLayout);


    mGLView.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        while( mGLView.isFocused() == false )
           {
                mGLView.requestFocus();
           }
        }
    });
}
```

and my Logcat looks like this.

```
KeyInputQueue        Enqueueing touch event1
KeyInputQueue        Enqueueing touch event0
KeyInputQueue        Enqueueing touch event1
KeyInputQueue        Enqueueing touch event0
KeyInputQueue        Enqueueing touch event1
KeyInputQueue        Enqueueing touch event0
..
WindowManager        Delivering pointer 1 > Window{com.myapplication/com.myapplication.activity}
WindowManager        Delivering pointer 0 > Window{com.myapplication/com.myapplication.activity}
WindowManager        Delivering pointer 1 > Window{com.myapplication/com.myapplication.activity}
KeyInputQueue        Enqueueing touch event0
WindowManager        Delivering pointer 0 > Window{com.myapplication/com.myapplication.activity}
KeyInputQueue        Enqueueing touch event1
WindowManager        Delivering pointer 1 > Window{com.myapplication/com.myapplication.activity}
..
```

I've also tried a single requestFocus() , but it gave same effect
Application becomes irresponsible at first seconds activity starts. Where did I wrong?
Thanks for all suggestions.
I am sorry for misexplanation, and for my language. I am a newbie for android platform, and this site.

Comment: I have also reimplemented `onTouchEvent()`, this methods aren't being called, both views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the mistake I did.
I was loading resources in views constructor. It was blocking android to doing stuff.
I've migrated resource loading into a child thread and problem fixed, a little.